# Can't get the last part of url

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the last part of this url string: `national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/`

my goal is get: `s11663` this is my code:

```
$path = parse_url("national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/", PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
$end = end($pathFragments);
var_dump($end);
```

but I get:

> string(0) ""

what I did wrong?

Comment: You can sanitise (remove spaces, slashes, etc from start and end) urls before exploding them.

Comment: Please, take a look at the edit of my answer. I added a code to work with urls ending with and without `/`

Comment: @FirstOne I see your second solution but I got this error: `Warning: substr() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in` the first, instead, working well. Thanks.

Comment: @SevengamesXoom, that's odd. It works for me [https://3v4l.org/BWjkd](https://3v4l.org/BWjkd)... I'll see what I can find

Comment: @SevengamesXoom, please, check it forcing the parameter 3 like this `(substr($path, -1, 1))` and let me know...

Comment: @FirstOne the link is not the same, change everytime for me. I don't know exactly why not working in the second solution but there isn't problem for me. The grabbed link are correct and with the slash

Comment: @SevengamesXoom, MAN!!! I just tested Saitama's code. HIS code is the one that is giving you that error, not mine... Please, check the person you are talking to!!!!

Comment: @FirstOne lol you're right. Haha sorry for the mistake, I'll check your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a trailing `/` in the end, you have to get the second last:

```
$path = parse_url("national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/", PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
array_pop($pathFragments); // remove last (empty value)
$end = end($pathFragments);
var_dump($end);
```

Take a look at the output of `$pathFragments` on your question:

```
Array
(
    [0] => national
    [1] => italy
    [2] => serie-a
    [3] => 20152016
    [4] => s11663
    [5] => 
)
```

---

This code will work for strings ending with **and** without `/`:

```
$path = parse_url("national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663", PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragmenst = (substr($path, -1) == '/') ? 
    $pathFragments = explode('/', $path, -1) :
    $pathFragments = explode('/', $path);

$end = end($pathFragments);
var_dump($end);
```

Output for `../s11663/`: https://3v4l.org/BWjkd

> string(6) "s11663"

Output for `../s11663`: https://3v4l.org/H7fP9

> string(6) "s11663"

---

**Notes:**

1 - This code:

```
$pathFragmenst = (substr($path, -1) == '/') ? 
    $pathFragments = explode('/', $path, -1) :
    $pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
```

Is short for this:

```
if(substr($path, -1) == '/'){
    $pathFragments = explode('/', $path, -1);
}else{
    $pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
}
```

---

2 - I don't know if that string is the result of the `url_parse`, or you are really trying to parse it, but

```
var_dump(parse_url("national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663", PHP_URL_PATH));
```

will output

> string(38) "national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663"

, so there is not need to `parse_url` it - unless you are trying to parse something like:

> http://example.com/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/ 
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I left it as is *in case* you are going to use the complete url...

Answer (score 5):

I your `$path` the string contains a `/` at the end so, when you explode that, the last `/` also gets counted and the last fragment contains nothing because there is nothing after the last `/`, So just remove the `/`.

```
$path = parse_url("national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663", PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
$end = end($pathFragments);
var_dump($end);
```

Or if you cannot remove that last `/`, then just `substr` the string:

```
$url = "national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/";
$url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url) - 1);
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
$end = end($pathFragments);
var_dump($end);
```

Hope it helps you!

**Update**

In the last example it just `substr`'s the last char get cut, no matter what char, so, what you can do is just as suggested by @firstone's comment, use rather than `$url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url) - 1);`, is:

```
$url = rtrim($url, "/");
```

OR, This:

```
if($url[strlen($url) - 1] == "/") {
    $url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url) - 1);
} else {
    // Let the url be as it is.....
}
```

Comment: Note that the second code doesn't work: `E_WARNING : type 2 -- substr() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given`

Comment: Thanks @FirstOne for notifying that! Changed the answer!

Comment: @Saitama If I pass this: `/national/italy/serie-a/c13` will return `c1` instead of `c13`.

Comment: @Saitama, _Just in case_ the url does **not** end with `/` (as in the previous comment ^), you could use `$url = rtrim($url, '/');` instead of `substr`. That way it won't the last char if it's not `/`...

Answer (score 2):

When you do `explode('/', $path);` the last element of the result array is empty because the last item will be the part after the last "/".

Either use one of the proposed solutions or switch to using `preg_match()`:

```
$end = '';
$path = parse_url("national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/", PHP_URL_PATH);

if(preg_match('#/([^/]+)/$#', $path, $matches)) {
  $end = $matches[1];
}

var_dump($end);
```

Comment: It's worth saying that since the op's added [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959084/cant-get-the-last-part-of-url#comment59574673_35959183), this answer will output `string(0) ""` in case it's missing the last `/` too